# display message after certain time using async task

Tags: timer, android-asynctask, runnable

I have a async task which is fetching records with API call.
Now I want to set a timer in activity which displays some toast message after 10-15 seconds if data in async task is taking time to load.

Toast message just to say "please wait...data is being loading."

There is an array in async task which is filled when reponse is proper.Now how can i track the condition when array is still empty because timer and async task runs independently.

What I tried is as follows

```
try{
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...Data loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

                }
            }, 10000);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But this is independent i.e if data is loaded then also this timer runs.

Can anyone help?